# Is there a way to be notified when my name is mentioned in Twitch?

Tags: twitch.tv

In Twitch chat, if your name is mentioned, it shows up with an inverse background (black in normal mode, white in theater mode). While this makes it easy to notice when you've been mentioned while you are watching chat, it doesn't do much for when you are not paying attention.

I'd like a way to get a desktop notification or sound notification when my name is mentioned in chat. Is this possible?

Also, is there a way to do this with any random keyword I'd like to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NightDev's [BetterTTV](https://nightdev.com/betterttv/) extension. It provides various enhancements to the twitch.tv website and it can be configured to provide desktop notifications and sounds on highlight. Note however that the latter of those two is currently labeled "BETA".

It does a lot more than what you're asking for but the structure of the extension seems to be pretty modular, so I imagine you can disable most, if not all annoyances you may have with it.

---

As a side note, I'd like to mention that you can interface with Twitch chat through any IRC client (see how [here](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc)).

Comment: This extension does exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Alexander covered a great answer with https://nightdev.com/betterttv/ The twitch IRC documentation was updated from his previous link:
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/ (can't comment rep too low)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to play a sound on Play Sound on "Highlight/Whisper — Get audio feedback for messages directed at you"  The setting is under the BetterTTV Settings

It's a very faint sound but it works!